# Joining two tables that has different datatypes below each other?

Tags: sql, oracle

For example there are 2 tables employees and departments generally when we use join then

[image]
**Employees.Employee_id**

```
|Employees.Dept_id|Departments.Dept_id|Departments.Department_name|Departments.location_id|
           x           x                      x                       x
           x           x                      x                       x
          x            x                      x                       x
```

what would be the query in this case.
The first would be

```
SELECT Employees.Employee_id,
  Employees.Dept_id,
  Departments.Dept_id,
  Departments.Department_name,
  Departments.location_id
FROM employees
FULL OUTER JOIN departments
ON Employees.Dept_id=Departments.Dept_id
```

what is the second one ???
Employees.Employee_id

```
|Employees.Dept_id|Departments.Dept_id|Departments.Department_name|Departments.location_id|
 X                X
 x                x
 x                x
                                       x                  x          x
                                       x                  x          x
                                       x                  x          x
```

Comment: Your picture is a little... large. Could you reduce it in size? I'm also completely not sure where the different datatypes come into this. What's the actual problem?

Comment: full outer join??? have you actually run this and verified all the results are what you want?

Comment: No the problem is that when u are joining two tables simultaneously they appear in the same row that means the data for ex let's say that employees.dept_id=16 will appear in the same row as departments.dept_id=16 now i want both the values to appear but in different rows. in row 1 employees.dept_id=16 and in row 2 departments.dept_id=16. and i want that the first row of the second table(departments table) to be completely blank(null).

Answer (score 0):

In the comments you are describing a non-join union.  Like this:

```
SELECT Employees.Employee_id,  Employees.Dept_id, NULL, NULL, NULL
FROM employees

UNION ALL

SELECT NULL, NULL,  Departments.Dept_id,  Departments.Department_name,  Departments.location_id
FROM departments
```

Comment: you must have a mistake then -- did you put `UNION` and not `UNION ALL`.  Just `UNION` by itself will show nothing in every case.